# Expression must have pointer- to- object type (vector of pointers)

Tags: c++

In my function `Delete` I have an error that says that `getTableColumns` must have a pointer-to-object type.

Class Column is an abstract class.

```
class Table {

    vector<Column*> _columns;
    Column* value;
    char* name;
public:
    vector<Column*> getTableColumns() {
        return _columns;
    }

void Delete(char* name, int columnNumber, string thisValue) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= findLongestColumn(); i++) {
                if ((string)thisValue.compare((string)(getTableColumns()
                     [columnNumber]->getColumnValues()[i])) == 0)//!!!error
                {...}    
        }
}
```

```
template <typename T>
class DataColumn : public Column {

    vector<T> values;

public:
    void getColumnValues()
    {
        return values;
    }
```

Comment: What do you think `[columnNumber]` means?

Comment: @Mari getTableColumns is a function without parameters. So this expression getTableColumns(
                     [columnNumber]->getColumnValues()[i]) does not make sense.

Comment: why are you c style casting a string which is already a string to a string?

Comment: [columnNumber] is  iterator

Comment: Ye gods. `if ((string)thisValue.compare((string)(getTableColumns()
                 [columnNumber]->getColumnValues()[i])) == 0)` wants to be four statements, not one.

Comment: no it is not an iterator, it is an index to a pointer in _columns;

Comment: I suppose the `return _columns;` instruction does much more than you expect...

Comment: You're gonna copy a lot this way

Answer (score 1):

`Column::getColumnValues` is declared `void` yet you return a value and then later index into the result.